# DHIS2 attribute category combination shows no dropdown list options

Tags: dhis2, categories

I created a attribute category  combination in the DHIS2, But for some reason when I choose the attribute category combination as part of my Dataset form, I can't see the list of category options in the dropdownlist (Partners list).

Why can't I see the list?  I'm sure that I followed the instruction correctly.